# How to Prevent Parent Component State from Resetting to Original after Closing the Child Component

Tags: reactjs

I have a search form with a lot of search components and a List container component which contains Item component to display the search results. When I click a selected Item, it pops up a Detail component. Right now, everything works fine except when clicking Close button inside the Detail component, the form gets reset and list of items also disappears. The Close button should just close the Detail component so I can select a different item in the list to view. What is the problem in my code? Thanks.
App.js

```
class App extends Component  {
state={ showPopup: false,
    selectedItem:'',
    Items:[]};
  togglePopup=()=> {  
this.setState({  

showPopup: !this.state.showPopup  
});  
 }  
onItemseSelect=(item)=>{
this.setState({selectedItem:item});
};

render(){
const Items=['aa','bb','cc'];
return(

<List 
Items={this.state.Items}
onItemSelect={this.onItemSelect}
onClick={this.togglePopup}
/>


{this.state.showPopup ?  
<Detail  
  item={this.state.selectedItem}
  closePopup={this.togglePopup.bind(this)}  
/>  
: null  
}  

);
}
}
```

List.js

```
import React  from 'react';
import Item from './Item';

const List=({Items,onItemSelect})=>{
    const renderedList= Items.map(item=>{
    return (
    <Item key={item.ID} item={item} onItemSelect={onItemSelect}  />
    );
})
return <div>

{renderedList}</div>
}

export default List;
```

Item.js

```
import React from 'react';
const Item=({item, onItemSelect})=>{
    return <div  onClick={()=>onItemSelect(item)} >
<div class="content">
<div class="header">
 {/*display contents*/}
View More
</div>
</div>
};
export default Item;
```

Detail.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Detail=({item,closePopup})=>{
    if (!item){
    return <div>loading</div>
    }

   return (
    <div className='popup'>
    <div className='popup_inner'>
     <p>
     {/*contents here*/}
     </p>

    <button onClick={()=>closePopup}>close me</button>
  </div>
</div>);
 };
export default Detail;
```

css code:

```
.popup {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
}
.popup_inner {
position: absolute;
left: 25%;
right: 25%;
top: 25%;
bottom: 25%;
margin: auto;
background: white;
}
```

No error message. The form resets to the original state.

Comment: Did you copy your `App` component verbatim? That should `throw` in runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here only, **I doubt how your list items are rendered first time only.**

```
Items:[]
```

```
render(){
const Items=['aa','bb','cc']; //static values which are not in use
return(

<List 
Items={this.state.Items} //You are using state which is blank
onItemSelect={this.onItemSelect}
onClick={this.togglePopup}
/>
...
)
}
```

Complete [Running code](https://jsfiddle.net/wjn4t812/#&togetherjs=j7Uq7T1ygf) is like this.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it later and report back. My pop up covers the whole screen when clicking on it and reset the parent after closing.

Comment: As `List` and `Detail` component are on same page, how the `Detail` component will take whole screen? Have you added some `CSS` to do so.

Comment: yes. The css makes the Detail component look like a pop up.

Comment: Post that css also, so that I can check what is happening.

Comment: I posted the css. see above. The reason I use const Items inside the render() is because the Items[] starts with a blank array. It gets updated by search results. And I am using a pagination to pass 100 items at a time. So I define a const Items=['aa','bb','cc'] to slice the total results here as an example.

Comment: How you have used `popup` and `popup_inner` classes in Details component, update that also.

Comment: It is working fine. Might be issue with your props. Check you are getting props correctly.

Comment: Nice job! I understand the problem is the initial state Items[] is blank and caused the problem. But my problem is the Items state will be updated when componentDidMount() api is called. I will keep working on it. Many thanks!

Comment: Finally, I found where the problem was. In Detail.js,   <button onClick={()=>closePopup}>close me</button> should be   <button onClick={closePopup}>close me</button>. Can you explain what is the difference because I am not very clear about the callback function.

Comment: arrow functions are suppose to send some parametes to parent component, in your case there is no parameter so it is not good to use arrow function. I have already told you this in my code snippet.

Comment: Thanks very much! I compared your code and my code and finally found the problem was. :/